# Transform.Find from child to Parent

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, transform

Here's the image for you guys to visual easier

[image]

The `ServerSelectUI` has the script where in I put this line of code

```
[SerializeField]
private Transform TurnOffShield = null;

TurnOffShield = transform.Find("");
```

I want to get the `Shields` GameObject. Could someone please help me out with finding from child to parents to another gameObject. Sorry for the weird question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
public Transform TurnOffShield;
TurnOffShield = GameObject.Find("Shields").transform;
```

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.Find.html

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
TurnOffShield = transform.parent.parent.Find("Shields");
```

but it would be better to simply reference it in the Inspector.

---

Alternatively if it has to be more flexible I sometimes do the following:

- Give `SceneSet` a certain MonoBehaviour (can be empty) like

  ```
  public class SceneSet : MonoBehaviour {}
  ```
- Give `Shields` a certain MonoBehaviour (can be empty) like

  ```
  public class Shields : MonoBehaviour {}
  ```

Now you can use

```
TurnOffShield = GetComponentInParent<SceneSet>().GetComponentInChildren<Shields>().transform;
```

Comment: you tried `TurnOffShield = transform.Find("");` .. what exactly didn't work?